# When writing a piece that will be published in multiple languages, are there any concessions a writer should make in tone, word choice, or style?

Tags: word-choice, translation, tone

The piece in question aims to be accessible, informal, and conversational. A bit of slang strikes the right tone to my American ear. Will it come off alright to other English speakers? Will translators be able to deal with what might be called Americanisms? It's literature for a self-help group. Translations are accomplished by members of a language community who work with a professional translator.

Comment: What are you writing? Depending on whether you're writing a novel, an article or a user manual, you'll get completely different answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to accommodate subsequent automatic translation](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10402/how-to-write-to-accommodate-subsequent-automatic-translation)

Comment: It's literature for a self-help group. Translations are accomplished by members of a language community who work with a professional translator.

Comment: Is your concern about compatibility between different dialects of English (as written), between translated versions, or both?

Comment: The project is to compile and edit contributions from multiple authors, the vast majority of whom are from North America. Since it's a bit of an anthology, the various pieces may resonate with some more than others and will sometimes take on regional tones, US-based or otherwise. The English should be comprehensible to other Anglophones. Translations will need to convey the same concepts but will be able to replace idioms, for example, where that's culturally appropriate.